# Windows phone 8 navigation to another page with many controls is extremely slow

Tags: windows-phone-8

I created an application in Android /IOS  and now I must create the application in Windows Phone. 
My problem is the navigation to a page with many controls is extremely slow and I would like to speed it up or show something to the user while it loads.  Currently what is happening is when the user clicks on a option in the menu, they have to wait like 5-8 sec before it loads the new page.  ( It looks like the button/application did not respond with the request of the user, and I  am sure you can understand why this is a big problem  ) InitializeComponent() is the cause of the delay. 
I don’t mind if InitializeComponent() takes it’s  time to load, but I would like to show something to the user while it is loading so it does not look the button did not respond. 
Is there any way to speed up this process or show at least a loading screen while the InitializeComponent() is loading its controls.

Comment: Why not use the built in progress bar control? In any case, 8 seconds seems like a lot of time so I would start by checking the controls you have on the view, binding modes and converters.
Just keep in mind that the info provided is far from enough to help you (except for standard advises like the one I mention).

Comment: To me it sounds like you are doing some processing when clicking the button that opens the page or before the page is actually shown. I have an app where I use pivots on a page with many controls and have no such issues. Maybe you can paste in the code of the Constructor, OnLoaded method if any and the button click handler that opens the page.